# Demonstrate that (1) and (2) are equal

Tags: self-learning, problem-solving, economics

$$DR_t= \frac{B_t}{P_t}-\frac{B_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}}\tag{1}$$

$$DR_t=\frac{NB_t}{P_t}- \pi_t\frac{B_{t-1}}{P_t}\tag{2}$$

Knowing that $\pi_t=\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}-1$ and $NB_t=B_t - B_{t-1}$, demonstrate that $(1)$ is equal to $(2)$.

So what I have done is substituted  $\pi_t$ and $NB_t$ into $(2)$ to get:

$$DR_t= \frac{B_t - B_{t-1}}{P_t} - \left(\frac{Pt}{P_{t-1}} -1\right) \frac{B_{t-1}}{P_t}$$

After that I made the following equation:

$$\frac{B_t - B_{t-1}}{P_t} - \left(\frac{Pt}{P_{t-1}} -1 \right)\frac{B_{t-1}}{P_t} = \frac{B_t}{P_t} - \frac{B_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}}$$

Now I have been trying to solve this equation in a variety of ways, since the first thing I tried (moving everything to one side and try to factor it all out) did not work. But without success.

Normally, I would go to my professor for help, but since we have to hand this in first thing after the weekend and got the assignment last Friday, I do not have time to do it.

A hint or just some recommended reading material in order to finish the assignment would suffice as well.

Thanks :)

Comment: Just manipulate the expession for $DR_t$ that you obtained from $(2)$ until it looks like equation $(1)$.

Comment: I have tried that, but somehow I am still stuck with an extra {B_{t-1}} in the equation.

Comment: Then try again (or show your working here), because you must have made a mistake somewhere

Comment: If I try to make equation (2) look like equation (1), this is what I end up with (see edited post). I feel like I am going in the complete wrong direction, but I have been looking at this for so long I cannot seem to get my head straight.

Comment: I am not sure where to start in pointing out the errors in the first line of your attempt. You are missing parentheses around $\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}-1$. Also, fractions do not sum the way you have added them. To add fractions first they need to have a common denominator and then you add them by summing the numerator (e.g. $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{3}{6}-\frac{2}{6}=1/6$, whereas in your working you have done something like $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1-1}{2-3}$, which makes no sense).

Comment: @Harry2016 [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AjwC.jpg) in the second line you cancel out the summand $ p_t$. This is not a valid mathematical transformation. You can cancel out **factors** only: $\frac{c\cdot a}{c}=\frac{\require{cancel} \cancel{c}\cdot a}{\require{cancel} \cancel{c}}=a$. But $\frac{c+ a}{c}\neq a$

Comment: Yes, I already thought that was how I remembered it from high school, but since I entered -1*(Bt-1/Pt-1) into the equation instead of (Pt/Pt-1 -1). I wasn't able to solve this so I started doing stupid things. Thanks anyways for the help, now I can get back to studying the basics :)

Comment: @Harry2016 I hope it is all clear now. If not feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know what went wrong at your transformations. My steps are the following:

$$\frac{B_t - B_{t-1}}{P_t} - \left(\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}} -1 \right)\frac{B_{t-1}}{P_t} $$

The first fraction can be splitted in two fractions:

$$\frac{B_t }{P_t}-\frac{B_{t-1}}{P_t} - \left(\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}} -1 \right)\frac{B_{t-1}}{P_t} $$

Multiplying out the brackets

$$\frac{B_t }{P_t}\color{blue}{-\frac{B_{t-1}}{P_t}} - \frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}\cdot \frac{B_{t-1}}{P_t} \color{blue}{+\frac{B_{t-1}}{P_t}}$$

The sum of the  blue terms are equal to zero. Finally cancel out.

Comment: This is a homework exercise and you have (almost) given him the complete answer!

Comment: @smcc I haven´t noticed it since it was tagged. Now I  notice that it is  mentioned in the text but  not before, sorry.